# Need help translating Python into R for text data

Tags: python, r, text, nlp

I am trying to create a dataset that only retains words from one dataset that exist in another. I know how to do this in Python but need to do it in R.
Here are two sample datasets. I want to return words from text_A that exist in text_B.

```
text_A= ['apple','cherry','kiwi','Tangerine','apple','apple','kiwi']
text_B= ['apple','banana','grapefruit','kiwi','mango','papaya', 'tangerine']

combined_words= [ ]
for x_words in text_A:
    if x_words in text_B:
        combined_words.append(x_words)

print(combined_words)
```

The output should be:
**'apple','kiwi','apple','apple','kiwi'**

Comment: you mean `intersect(text_A, text_B)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text_A <- c('apple','cherry','kiwi','Tangerine','apple','apple','kiwi')
text_B <- c('apple','banana','grapefruit','kiwi','mango','papaya', 'tangerine')

text_A[text_A %in% text_B]
## [1] "apple" "kiwi"  "apple" "apple" "kiwi"
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
text_A= c('apple','cherry','kiwi','Tangerine','apple','apple','kiwi')
text_B= c('apple','banana','grapefruit','kiwi','mango','papaya', 'tangerine')

intersect(text_A, text_B)
[1] "apple" "kiwi"
```